# WP8 App opens by tapping on Toast

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, toast

I'm developing an application for windows phone 8. I need to check if my app is opened by tapping on a toast notification. How can I do that?

Suppose I cannot get any information from the toast.

Answer (score 3):

If you check out the MSDN article here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662938(v=vs.105).aspx, you'll see that it is possible to add extra information to the toast that you can use in your app!

**Deep linking to a screen using toast notifications**
You can use the Param element or NavigateUri property, depending on how you're creating the toast notification, to deep link to a specific screen in your app. Here are the allowed formats. Any string used for the following examples must be 256 characters or less.

**/page1.xaml** – Defines the screen to navigate to in the app when the app starts. The string must begin with a "/".

**/page1.xaml?value1=1234 &value2=9876** – Defines the screen to navigate to when the app starts, along with name/value pairs of info. The string must begin with a "/".

**?value1=1234 &value2=9876** – Contains name/value pairs of info passed to the default start screen of the app. The string must begin with a "?".

Comment: Thanks but the sad thing is I cannot do that in this situation :(

Comment: Ow that's unlucky... not sure how you could get any other info in your app.

Comment: But if it's his app, how can he have no control over the push notifications? Am I missing something and it is possible for a 3rd party to produce Toasts that target my App?

Comment: I'm using Parse.com to push notifications and sadly I cannot specify the 'param' for my notification. Everything else works well