# Deep linking to page from toast notification in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, toast, deep-linking

I'm trying to open a specific page in my app (not the home page) and use the following piece of code

```
private void toastNotification(string Content,string uri)
{
        XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);
        XmlNodeList textElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        textElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("FootBallTards"));
        textElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(Content));


        var toastNavigationUriString = "/Views/Browser.xaml?uri="+uri;
        var toastElement = ((XmlElement)toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast"));
        toastElement.SetAttribute("launch", toastNavigationUriString);

        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(new ToastNotification(toastXml)); 
}
```

The toast notification is being fired correctly but on tapping them, the home located in Views/Home.xaml (absolute address) page of my app is being opened, but I want to redirect to page located in Views/Browser.xaml (absolute address), and also pass the parameter uri to that page.

Apart from this how can I get the value of parameter on that page. I've looked up help from [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358711/wp8-app-opens-by-tapping-on-toast) , [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927307/how-to-deep-link-push-notification-in-wp8) and [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662938(v=vs.105).aspx) but couldn't get it to work.